# Wondershaper does not work

Tags: linux, centos, bandwidth, bandwidth-control

I am using wondershaper to limit download upload speed. What it does is, it limits download but then it blocks upload. I have an 1 gbit connection and 
I want to limit it's download speed to 500 mbps and upload speed to 500 mbps.

The command I'm using for this is:

```
wondershaper eth0 9798 9790
```

Here is the link to my config: http://pastebin.com/WBqj1H1Y

I have tried to change the numbers but still upload is blocked for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

Your command syntax looks wrong. To limit download and upload speed on interface eth0 to 512 Kbps try this:

```
wondershaper -a eth0 -d 512 -u 512
```

Please read about wondershaper here:

https://github.com/magnific0/wondershaper

Comment: hello i have installed this version of wondershaper then run this command  /usr/bin/wondershaper -a eth0 -d 62500 -u 62500 i still can not upload it limit the upload speed to 2kbs

Comment: Speed: 4.70 KBps. Remaining: 11 hours 3 minutes 56 seconds

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess, I'd guess you were using a very old wondershaper - this is something that just caused me a problem. Ubuntu/Debian distros include wondershaper 1.1 which uses the command-line you displayed, while the first answer from Diamant are based off what appears to be a more modern version.

There are open issues related to this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wondershaper

...but as of Ubuntu 18.04LTS, the packaged wondershaper does not work correctly out of the box so you have to go direct to the github repo from magnific0

Comment: Yes, just grab it from Github instead of using old Ubuntu/Debian distros